# Multiplication of 2 singular distributions(Dirac Delta times Shifted Dirac Delta)

Tags: dirac-delta

I already know that $\delta^{2}(t)$ is not defined.

However consider $A(t) = \delta(t) \cdot \delta(t-t_0)\ $ with $ t_0 \neq 0 $. Can I claim that $A(t) = 0$ ?
If that is the case, is there a way to prove it besides just using the non rigorous argument that $\delta(t) = 0$, $\forall t \neq 0$ and $\delta(0) = \infty$. Even then we would have $@t = 0$ for example $0 \cdot \infty$ which is indeterminate.

Comment: Yes. Since they  have disjoint distributional support they can be multiplied. I would suggest this nice pedagogical note https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1778

Comment: How do you define $A(t)$? At the end, the fact that this distribution is $0$ is almost the definition of the product in this case ...

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ have disjoint [singular support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Singular_support) then the product of them can be defined.

Comment: Thank you, I think with those links I am satisfied
@LL3.14 A(t) is just a notation I used to represent this product. I have not studied distributions and generalised functions in depth. In the previous year I came across with dirac delta and now in some proof I needed to know if this computed  to zero. Any course recommendation from Mathematics Dept. that deals with distributions in more detail is appreciated. Thank you again for the help